# Index + Match equivalent for Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe containing a column with dates and a column with a list of stock prices. I want to print a message that reports the highest observed stock price along with the corresponding date it was observed.
This problem in Excel would be solved by using a `vlookup`, `index-match` or a simple `.offset(0,-1)` function. 
What is the Python equivalent? I am not interested in creating a new column, but simply printing the date.

Example of my dataframe (`data_df`):

[image]

Snippet of my code:

```py
    max1 = data_df.loc[:, ticker].max()
    max1_date = "test" #data_df.loc[data_df.idxmax(axis=0,skipna=True), 'Date']

    print("The highest stock price observed at: \n", ticker, ":", max1.round(2), "USD on the date ", max1_date
         )
```

where `ticker` is generated elsewhere in my code. In this example ticker is **ATVI**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with  `next` and `iter` for get first matched value and if value not match, get string `no match`:

```
max1_date = next(iter(data_df.loc[data_df[ticker] == max1, 'Date']), 'no match')
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved by it setting:
`max1_date = data_df[data_df[ticker] == max1]['Date'].values[0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
data_df.iloc[data_df.ATVI.idxmax()]
```